# Cannot add "dist" folder to github repo

Tags: git, addition

When I create folder named `dist` and add anything to it github fails to see new additions.

`git add .` reports that all is up do date.

any reason for that?

Comment: Check your gitignore.

Comment: yeah had same issue,saw the replies on here and just commented out the /dist line in .gitignore file. thanks guys.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most probably you have a`dist` entry in your project's `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score -1):

You cant add folder in git. Add for exemple à .gitignore file in the folder and commit it. Check on the forum for more détails ;)